# Preventing unsafe dereferencing of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, unique-ptr

Taken from a slide at cppcon2015:

```
unique_ptr<A> f() {
   auto a = make_unique<A>();
   return a;
}

//Why does this even compile?
const A & dangling = *f(); 

//BOOM!!!
use(dangling);
```

My question is: with rvalue references for *this, can this be solved?

I see in the spec in cppreference:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const;
```

Question:

1. Would it make sense to disallow `operator*` for rvalue `unique_ptr`s  and only have dereference valid for lvalue `unique_ptr`s?
2. There are still valid use cases to keep the rvalue `unique_ptr` dereferenceable?

Like this:

```
//Make sure it is an lvalue.
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const &;
```

NOTE: I am not sure of the syntax or correctness, I have no experience with rvalue references for *this.

Comment: Did you mean `*f();` instead of `f();` ?

Comment: btw. `const&` would still allow the implicit object to be an rvalue

Comment: What about `auto non_dangling = f()` to avoid the problem? Is it really the pointer that needs to be fixed?

Comment: The correct spec would be without const? Is what I am asking for even possible?

Comment: @BoPersson The question is more about if this is possible to avoid, even if stupid. Machine-enforceable.

Comment: @GermánDiago removing `const` would in turn disable this operator for const lvalues. you probably want to `=delete` an additional `const&&` overload

Comment: If you write the reply for the correct spec I will be grateful, you know... or I do it myself?

Comment: @GermánDiago I think that "*There are still valid use cases to keep the rvalue unique_ptr dereferenceable*" but I'm curious to see the answers

Comment: If you disable that dereferencing operator could you then use it like `use(*f())`?

Comment: C++ doesn't track lifetime, Rust does.

Comment: @JurajBlaho so that is a use case I was looking for that is valid even if unique_ptr is an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *My question is: with rvalue references for `*this`, can this be solved?*

Technically yes. One solution would be to introduce an additional (deleted) overload for rvalues:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const&& = delete;
//                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

and to modify the existing one by means of adding a ref-qualifier:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const&;
//                                                         ~~^~~
```

Since rvalues strongly prefer to be bound by an rvalue reference, any attempt to dereference an rvalue expression involving a `unique_ptr` would result in a compile error - "use of deleted function".

> *Would it make sense to disallow `operator*` for rvalue `unique_ptrs` and only have dereference valid for lvalue `unique_ptrs`?*

Not always. And because of that I doubt the library should impose additional constraints on the `unique_ptr` specification, only to prevent a possible misuse.

> *There are still valid use cases to keep the rvalue `unique_ptr` dereferenceable?*

The lifetime of a temporary ends at the end of a full expression that the temporary is part of. This means that the object obtained from dereferencing a `unique_ptr` is valid as long as the associated `unique_ptr` is alive, so the below use-cases are valid, and wouldn't be possible if `operator*` was disabled for rvalues:

```
(*f()).foo();
//          ^~~ unique_ptr is destroyed here


use(*f());
//       ^~~ unique_ptr is destroyed here
```